# ubuntu 12.04 Wifi not working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager

My wifi is not working since I uninstalled network-manager-gnome.

The output of

```
sudo lshow -C network
```

is

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:21:5d:9c:b9:c6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.11.0-22-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:47 memory:98700000-98701fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:85:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:22:64:57:9a:33
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:98600000-98603fff ioport:2000(size=256)
```

How do i enable my wifi on the terminal since I don't have the network manager GUI.

Doing

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

returned this error

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

and when I used sudo I got

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

Doing

```
lsmod
```

returned

```
    Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          12617  0 
usb_storage            48631  0 
pci_stub               12550  1 
vboxpci                22910  0 
vboxnetadp             13328  0 
vboxnetflt             27240  0 
vboxdrv               252210  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
bnep                   19210  2 
rfcomm                 59026  12 
snd_hda_codec_analog    75690  1 
parport_pc             32114  0 
ppdev                  17423  0 
arc4                   12509  2 
iwldvm                226487  0 
binfmt_misc            17268  1 
mac80211              534971  1 iwldvm
uvcvideo               72275  0 
snd_hda_intel          43326  2 
videobuf2_core         39385  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_codec         169608  2 snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_intel
videodev              107944  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                94597  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
videobuf2_vmalloc      13048  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25157  1 snd_seq_midi
btusb                  23534  0 
i915                  615880  3 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_memops       13170  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
bluetooth             341971  24 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
iwlwifi               153182  1 iwldvm
snd_seq                55716  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28930  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
drm_kms_helper         47306  1 i915
drm                   247722  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
psmouse                92826  0 
snd                    61270  14 snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12600  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18398  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
cfg80211              416271  3 iwldvm,mac80211,iwlwifi
joydev                 17329  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13316  1 i915
serio_raw              13189  0 
hp_wmi                 17834  0 
lpc_ich                16987  0 
hp_accel               25756  0 
sparse_keymap          13658  1 hp_wmi
video                  19046  1 i915
lis3lv02d              19600  1 hp_accel
wmi                    18744  1 hp_wmi
mac_hid                13077  0 
input_polldev          13648  1 lis3lv02d
lp                     13359  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
ahci                   25703  2 
sky2                   53656  0 
libahci                30834  1 ahci
```

Doing

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

returned

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hp-gps: GPS
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
4: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

running

```
lspci -nn | grep -i net
```

returned

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection [8086:4237]
85:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4357]
```

I do not understand why am getting this error and I have not uninstalled my wifi drivers which were working well before

Comment: What is the position of the wireless switch or slider on your laptop?

Comment: There is no switch or slider

Comment: Does it work if you do, in a terminal: sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi and then: sudo rfkill unblock all? If so, we can blacklist hp-wmi.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I just did that and then sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we now know that *hp-wmi* is blocking your wireless, let's blacklist it:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist hp-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You can download some network manager offline from another source of internet (as a .deb file) and then install it on your ubuntu and go from there.
Most famous network managers are network-manager and wicd. I personally prefer wicd because network-manager had a lot of bugs with my wireless chipset.
You can go from there since you now have a connection manager.